# Trying to create azure mysql flexible server using terraform

Tags: mysql, azure, terraform

trying to create azure mysql flexible server:

```
resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server" "flexible_mysql" {
  name                   = "kjghfbdretyhmysql"
  resource_group_name    = "CYARC-TF-DEV-RG-EA-001"
  location               = "East US"
  version                = "8.0.21"
  administrator_login    = "adminuser"
  administrator_password = "Internet@123"
  backup_retention_days  = 7 #1to 35 days  
  geo_redundant_backup_enabled   = false  
  sku_name               = "Standard_B1ms"
  storage {
    auto_grow_enabled    = true
    iops                 = 640
    size_gb              = 20
  }

}
```

Gives the following error

```
Error: "sku_name" is not a valid sku name, got Standard_B1ms
│ 
│   with module.Create-trail.azurerm_mysql_flexible_server.flexible_mysql,
│   on trail\main.tf line 10, in resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server" "flexible_mysql":
│   10:   sku_name               = "Standard_B1ms"
```

Some help is appreciated

Comment: B_Standard_B1s worked successfully. thank you Vinay. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to provision the Azure MySQL flexible server using Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully

The error message you're encountering indicates that the `sku_name` value "Standard_B1ms" is not recognized as a valid SKU (Stock Keeping Unit) for Azure MySQL Flexible Server.

Azure MySQL Flexible Server SKUs are typically formatted differently. For example, you might see SKUs like "GP_Standard_D2s_v3" or "MO_Standard_E2s_v3" for general-purpose and memory-optimized configurations, respectively.

To resolve this error please update the
**`Standard_B1ms`** with **`B_Standard_B1s`**

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demovkdb-rg"
  location = "east US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-vn"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "demovk-sn"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
  delegation {
    name = "fs"
    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.DBforMySQL/flexibleServers"
      actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "demovk.mysql.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "demovkVnetZone.com"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_flexible_server" "example" {
  name                   = "demovk-fs"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  administrator_login    = "psqladmin"
  administrator_password = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
  backup_retention_days  = 7
  delegated_subnet_id    = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  private_dns_zone_id    = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id
  sku_name               = "B_Standard_B1s"

  depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.example]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[MySQL flexible server does not accept sku name Standard_B1s · Issue #15538 · hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm · GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/15538)